# Finding and listing invites for a server

Tags: c#, discord.net

I did this an eternity ago with like... My first bot. I managed to grab all the invites for a server my bot was in, and then list them into an Embed. If there wasn't one, it would make one and then list it.

Problem is, I somehow lost the code to that bot, and don't remember how I did it. Anybody got any ideas how I'd pull this off again?

Comment: invites exist on `TextChannels` there is a method `GetInvitesAsync()` that will return all invites to that channel. If you want all for the guild, you'd have to loop through all text channels for the guild -- `Guild.TextChannels`

Comment: Epic, got it. Thanks.